# Need suggestion on hibernate for the requirement

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables (category and subcategory)

Here is my Category Model

```
    @Table(name = "category")

public class Category {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int mCat_Id;

    @Column(name = "category" , unique = true)
    @JsonProperty("category")
    private String mCategory;
    }



public class SubCategory {

   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int mSub_Cat_Id;

   @Column(name = "subcategory")
   @JsonProperty("subcategory")
   private String mSubCategory; 

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;
}
```

and input

```
record 1:
{"subcategory":"ss" , "category":{ "category":"upsc"}}
record 2:
{"subcategory":"science" , "category":{ "category":"upsc"}}
```

it is adding upsc as a new record whenever I pass the different sub category and category remains same.

My requirement is: when I am passing similar category then It should not create a record in the category table.

Am I missing anything? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

**Expected Result :**

```
Category table > 1 record > category : upsc  , category_Id : 1 

SubCategory table > 2 records > 
      subcategoty : science ,  category_Id : 1  , subcategory_id : 1 
      subcategoty : ss,  category_Id : 1  , subcategory_id : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a OneToOne relationship? Seeing the input that you provide it should be as I have below.

```
Entity
@Table(name = "sub_category")
public class SubCategory {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "subcategory_id")
  private int subCategoryId;

  @Column(name = "subcategory")
  private String subCategory;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
  private Category category;
}
```

Is your Category class similair to mine?

```
Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "category_id")
  private int categoryId;

  @Column(name = "category")
  private String category;
}
```

It should not add new records to the Category class now.
You also have to remove `CascadeType.ALL`, that instructs Hibernate to save all associations.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but no luck.. Is ManyToOne relation is fine for my requirement or I need to take care one by one ? or any other way to acheive my requirement ?

Comment: No luck? Meaning it still adds a new row inside the Category table?
If your Category only has one SubCategory you should keep the OneToOne relationship and simple remove the CascadeType.ALL attribute. Like so `@OneToOne`... Adding more code to see whats actually happening will also help.